# How can a user re-join a secret Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I created a secret group in Facebook where all of my friends can talk and chat about anything. If someone leaves the group and wants to join the group, what can they do?

I am the admin of that group, but when I try to add the user back, it prompts with the error:

> You have no authority to add that person

I also have tried making the group open and asking him to search and join back in. But it also fails.

Since it is a secret group, nobody can search for it. He can neither join again nor admin (myself) can add him.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[My friend left my group. How can I send a second invitation?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=100531910040062#My-friend-left-my-group.-How-can-I-send-a-second-invitation?)**
>   Unfortunately, you will not be able to send a second group invitation to the same friend. The person will have to request to join the group again.

That's from [Facebook Help](https://www.facebook.com/help?page=982), so my best suggestion is to make it open (or even closed, since one can ask to join a closed group) and let this take effect before your friend starts searching it. I could be wrong, but my guess is he could not find/join it because of the fact that the change is not instant.

Answer (score 3):

Can also confirm that a direct link to the secret group does work! A re-request is submitted and an admin is required to approve the request to re-join. But it is NOT necessary to change the status of the group from secret to closed or open.

To obtain a working link go to group's home page and copy the URL from the address bar—will look something like `https://www.facebook.com/groups/_________`

This solution does work. But note that you may have previously bookmarked the secret group URL as such:

```
/group.php?gid=123456789etc...
```

And in this case you may get a "page not found" message (that's what happened to me).

If you replace it with:

```
/groups/123456789etc...
```

You may then be able to access the group landing page and request access to the group.

Comment: I was unable to change our group status as admin because Facebook says the group is too large to change the settings to a lower privacy status. Weird. But, I was able to send the link to the group and the person requested in that way.